# How to import database into vagrant mysql?

Tags: mysql, vagrant, vagrant-windows

In window cmd ,I usually do like this and it is working

```
C:\Users\davi> mysql -u root -p mydb < D:/xampp/mysql/bin/db.sql
```

I am new in vagrant , this is what I do in vagrant ssh

```
[vagrant@localhost bs]$ mysql -u root -p mydb < D:/xampp/mysql/bin/db.sql
```

But I got this error

> -bash: D:/xampp/mysql/bin/db.sql: ??????????????????????

Is there anyway to import correctly ?

Comment: Probably path is wrong. In Vargant files have different location. Read about `mount` etc.. https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You do not have `D:/xampp/mysql/bin/db.sql` from your vagrant VM

1. Place the file `db.sql` in the same folder where you have the Vagrantfile
2. `vagrant ssh` as you normally do to get into the VM
3. run the following command to import the db

   ```
   $ mysql -u root -p mydb < /vagrant/db.sql
   ```

The `/vagrant` folder is a default shared folder in the VM.

Comment: this helps me save a lot of time searching for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Copy DB.sql under your project folder in Windows

In Vagrant after mysqling into database, you can access your source /var/www/PROJECTNAME/DB.sql